# When i attempt implement Promise.all with typescript, UnhandledPromiseRejection error happened , and i don't know how to handle this error?

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

implement code

i attempt to implement promise all with ts

```js
Promise.myAll = function <T>(values: T[]): Promise<Awaited<T>[]> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const result: Awaited<T>[] = [];
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      Promise.resolve(values[i])
        .then((res) => {
          result[i] = res;
          count++;
          if (count === values.length) resolve(result);
        })
        .catch(reject);
    }
  });
};
const p = Promise.myAll([1, 2, 3]);
const p2 = Promise.myAll([1, 2, 3, Promise.reject(444)]);

// const p3 = Promise.myAll([1, 2, 3, Promise.reject(555)]);

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(p);
  console.log(p2);
});
```

index.d.ts

```
interface PromiseConstructor {
  myAll<T>(values: T[]): Promise<Awaited<T>[]>;
}
```

my launch json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "ts-node",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "${relativeFile}"
            ],
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-r",
                "ts-node/register"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
        }
    ]
}
```

when i run myAll code, the following happened, i found nothing online about familar question.

[image]

Could anyone help me explain the error, and how to fix this error?

I have attempted the following troubleshooting steps:

- Checked if the library is correctly imported and ensured that the version matches the documentation.
- Thoroughly reviewed the official documentation and code examples to ensure that I am correctly understanding and utilizing the library's API.
- Tried different parameters and configuration options based on suggestions from the community.

Comment: well, yes, you don't handle the rejected promise in `p2` - so this is an expected result - i.e. `p2` is a rejected Promise with no `.catch`

Comment: As an example of how to catch the error, add this to the end of your code: `p2.catch(err => console.error(err))`

Comment: Thanks, beacause it's myAll,eslint didn't find error

Comment: Don't put functions on global namespaces. Leave `Promise` alone and just declare `function myAll(...` . But also, what is the purpose of this code? What is this supposed to do that regular typing with `Promise.all` can't do?